# What is the difference between module_init and subsys_initcall while initializing the driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

What is the difference between `module_init` and `subsys_initcall` while initializing the driver?

Comment: Did you check the man pages?

Comment: No manual page entry available for that.

Comment: You can always grep through the sources. A great deal can be explained by just looking at the sources.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The difference relates to timing, or more precisely, order of execution.  That is, the procedure declared as `subsys_initcall` is guaranteed to be executed before the procedure declared as `module_init`.  This ordering ensures that subsystem and platform drivers are initialized before device drivers try to utilize the former's functionality (e.g. a device driver registers as a subsystem device).

The actual macro definition for each depends on if the kernel is configured for (loadable) modules or not.  The definition for these macros (and other init macros) can be found in [include/linux/init.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/init.h?v=3.7)

Note that `subsys_initcall()` can only be used by a built-in (statically linked) module.
`module_init` can be used by either built-in or loadable modules.

Comment: For loadable `*.ko` modules, `subsys_initcall()` is mapped to the same as `module_init()` i.e. `device_initcall()` Reference: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/init.h#L298